# Angular service return undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-services

I have a problem with my service in angular.

My service has the next code:

```
app.service("Utilidades", ['$http', '$window', function ($http, $window) {
return {
    Get: function (urlAbsoluta, parametros, callback) {
        var Utilidades = this;

        $http
            .get(app.UrlBase + urlAbsoluta, parametros)
            .then(function (data) {
                var Datos = angular.fromJson(data);

                Utilidades.GuardarToken(Datos.Token);

                callback(Datos);
            });
    },


    ObtenerMenu: function () {
        var Utilidades = this;

        Utilidades.Get("Administracion/Api/Usuarios/Menu", {}, function (Datos) {
            Datos = angular.fromJson(Datos.data);

            if (Datos.Error == "") {
                return Datos.Resultado;
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        });
    }
}
}]);
```

Then, in my controller i have the next code:

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'Utilidades',
function Iniciador($scope, $http, $location, Utilidades) {
        var Li = this;

        Li.Usuario = "";
        Li.Contrasena = "";
        Li.Error = "";
        Li.MenuItems = [];

        Li.Menu = function () {
            Li. MenuItems = Utilidades.ObtenerMenu();
        }
    }]
);
```

When i run this, Li.MenuItems have undefined value and i don't know why.

Comment: You're missing a `;` after your service's `return {...}`

Comment: This happens because the "return" you are doing is for "function (Datos) {"
not for "ObtenerMenu: function () {".

You approched this known problem well with the callback in your Get function. I cannot suggest any solution for I do not know one, accept for syncronic ajax which is unacceptable.

Comment: Is ti because of the space after Li.? " Li. MenuItems = Utilidades.ObtenerMenu();"

Comment: Are you calling Li.Menu()?

Comment: @BenTaliadoros No, that space has no effect on the code's behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `return` statements are in a function *inside* your `ObtenerMenu` method so the `ObtenerMenu` method is not actually returning anything. You need to provide a way to access the resulting value:

**Service**

```
app.service("Utilidades", ['$http', '$window', function ($http, $window) {
    return {
        Get: function (urlAbsoluta, parametros) {
            var Utilidades = this;

            // v------------  return statement here
            return $http
                .get(app.UrlBase + urlAbsoluta, parametros)
                .then(function (data) {
                    var Datos = angular.fromJson(data);

                    Utilidades.GuardarToken(Datos.Token);

                    // v------------  return statement here
                    return Datos;
                });
        },


        ObtenerMenu: function () {
            var Utilidades = this;

            // v------------  return statement here
            return Utilidades.Get("Administracion/Api/Usuarios/Menu", {})
                .then(function (Datos) {
                    if (Datos.Error == "") {
                        return Datos.Resultado;
                    } else {
                        return "";
                    }
                });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**In Controller**

```
Li.Menu = function () {
    Utilidades.ObtenerMenu()
        .then(function (resultado) {
             Li. MenuItems = resultado;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `ObtenerMenu` function is asynchronous function. This function doesn't return anything initially (so undefined) and later, after some time when ajax request finishes, this function is already finished its execution stack